# procedure parameter is int, but when procedure is called with a double, it compiles

Tags: mysql, variable-assignment

As you can see below, I have two parameters for the procedure. I want them to be both integers. However, when I tested the procedure with a non-integer, it still compiled! Why?

```
 create procedure int_arith( p_1 int, p_2 int)
 begin
  select coalesce(p_1 + p_2, 'Null entry') addition;
 end;
 #

 call test.a03_int_arith(10,3.3)\G
```

the result was:

```
        addition: 13
```

Comment: Because it converts double to int implicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is valid in some languages to promote a double to an int (see type conversion).
What is happening is the interpreter (compiler whatever) sees the double, in this 3.3, and truncates it to an  integer (implicitly casts the double to an int).

Comment: Hm... so I would need to create a case argument for this? To avoid letting it make a conversion? Thanks.

Comment: Or you could make you them doubles (the only way I know of anyway). You can't predict what the user inputs. And doubles makes the most sense.

Comment: I want to make sure that they user only inputs integers. So avoid a conversion. Thanks again.

Comment: `MOD(n, 1)` returns the fractional part of a number, you can check that this is 0. Or you could declare the input as a string and check that it only contains digits and an optional sign prefix.